# How do I create a static framed ASCII interface in Python?

Tags: python, terminal

When I use the `less` command in my Mac Terminal I'm shown a 23 row slice of the specified file.  If I move down the file, then scroll up in the terminal window, I don't see any file content before the current slice.  Instead, I see the commands I typed before using `less`.

I would like to use this or a similar effect to create an ascii game interface that shows only the current screen, with no history.  I would draw my frames on screen and change only the text or options within those frames.  This is very common in older systems that ran mostly or entirely in a command line environment.

Is there a Python module that offers this?  Is it an effect that I can or should implement myself?

Here are some example screen elements that could benefit from this effect.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                   |
| Dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog    |
| dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog    |
| dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog    |
| dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog dialog    |
| dialog dialog dialog dialog.                                      |
|                                                                   |
|                                                                   |
|                                                                   |
+--------------------+---------------+------------------------------+
|   Attack           |     South     |            HP/Max   MP/Max   |
| > Cast Magic       |       -       |   Tom:    120/120   60/91    |
|   Use Item         |      New      | > Dick:    27/133   47/47    |
|   Tactics          |  Schwartzton  |   Harry:   87/104   16/113   |
+--------------------+---------------+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest looking into the [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html) module. It's an interface to the `ncurses` library, which is used for exactly this purpose (I believe many terminal applications are written in it). The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) is quite decent, and there are several nice [tutorials](http://www.dev-explorer.com/articles/python-with-curses) that should also set you in the right direction.

(Either that or liberal use of `\r`.) I would strongly suggest the `curses` module, since it should provide more flexibility for what you're looking to do.

EDIT: If you're interested in creating a cross-platform application, keep in mind that the `curses` module is only available on *nix systems. Per the documentation:

> No one has made a Windows port of the curses module.

That tutorial recommends [this library](http://effbot.org/zone/console-index.htm) for use on Windows, although if the dates on the download page are any indication, it has not been updated in a fair amount of time. You could look into [this module](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses), which looks considerably more recent.

Comment: This is great!  Fortunately, I'm in a Unix/Linux community, so I can focus on that.  I'll bookmark the `console` module for later.

Comment: This post is rather old, and the curses page now indicates that a Windows port exists at [this page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/UniCurses).

Comment: The windows port is UniCurses but in pypy I see Last released: Jan 29, 2012...

Answer (score 8):

I've been struggling with this issue too.  I wanted a simple cross platform solution, so I extended [asciimatics](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics) to provide a set of [widgets](http://asciimatics.readthedocs.org/en/stable/widgets.html) to create form-based UIs like this.  For example:

[image: Text UI widgets]

The resulting code should be quite concise and work on any modern OS (including Windows, Linux and OSX) without installing extra native libraries.  As you can see from the [contact list sample](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics/blob/master/samples/contact_list.py) the standard widgets are easy to lay out and should provide most of your needs.

Answer (score 3):

What you're talking about is `curses`. It is a Python module that interfaces with ncurses. The best tutorial that I've found for using `curses` is this one: http://www.dev-explorer.com/articles/python-with-curses

Some popular programs that use curses (albeit from another language) are aptitude and nano.

Comment: aptitude and nano use curses.  vim uses termcap (not curses).  wget and inks are hardcoded (no curses).